# CSS3 unicode-range does not work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, unicode-range

I'm using `CSS3` property `unicode-range` to set different fonts for different character sets. `Arial` for Latin characters and a `WebNazanin` for Arabic/Farsi. It seems to work in Chrome 29 and IE10 but not in Firefox 23, it still uses `Arial` font in Firefox:

**Chrome screenshot**:

[image: Chrome]

---

**Firefox screenshot**:
[image: Firefox]

It's my css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebNazanin';
    src: url('http://awebfont.ir/services/fonts/775b712c01cdf4eb7f15d9180567345060f700291901931.eot'),
    url('http://awebfont.ir/services/fonts/775b712c01cdf4eb7f15d9180567345060f700291901931.otf') format('opentype'),url('http://awebfont.ir/services/fonts/775b712c01cdf4eb7f15d9180567345060f700291901931.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://awebfont.ir/services/fonts/775b712c01cdf4eb7f15d9180567345060f700291901931.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://awebfont.ir/services/fonts/775b712c01cdf4eb7f15d9180567345060f700291901931.svg') format('svg');
}
@font-face {
    font-family:'WebNazanin';
    src: local('Times New Roman');
    unicode-range: U+41-7F;

}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/t9MpF/

Comment: By “Arial”, you mean “Times New Roman”, right? (Judging from the screen shots and the CSS code.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela ah, maybe, Arial or Times New Roman, no differences, just I want a different font.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are correct. Firefox does not support `unicode-range`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-range#Browser_compatibility

They are working on it. Since [4 years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=475891).

If it's really important to you, you may need to search for a javascript solution (like looking at every char and inserting styled `span`s and such...). But that could probably be sensibly slow.

### UPDATE

It's now implemented, but not enabled by default. You can enable it with an `about:config` flag (`layout.css.unicode-range.enabled`)

Answer (score 2):

it's old but a simple solution is:

```
font-family: WebNazanin, Arial;
```

I always using this method, it will display WebNazanin for arabic or persian chars and Arial for Latin.